# What does [BX] mean in this part of code?

Tags: pointers, assembly, emu8086

I have this code which is a alternative to print a string of characters using the loop command.

```
data segment

mystr db "Hello World!" 


ends



code segment
start:

mov ax, data
mov ds, ax  

lea bx,mystr 

mov cx,50

L1:

   mov dl,[BX]
   inc BX
   cmp dl,'!'
   je L2
   mov ah,02
   int 21h
   
loop L1
 
L2:
 
 
    
    
    
 
         


mov ax, 4c00h 
int 21h    
ends

end start
```

The lea command saves mystr to the BX register what does [BX] mean and why does incrementing the BX value gives us access to different parts of the string?

Comment: Yes, it does - `bx` is used as an index into `mystr` here. - the `lea` does not exactly save `mystr` to the `bx` register, it loads a pointer to its first element.

Comment: The string is a data structure that lives in memory.  Thus, every byte of the string has a memory address, and the addresses increment by 1 for each byte in the string.  We can refer to the whole string using the address of its first byte, which is what the `lea bx` is doing: loading the value of the memory address of the first byte into `bx`.  `[bx]` dereferences the address held in `bx`, so brings a single character into the `dl` register. Incrementing the value in `bx` updates its value to the next memory address in the string.

Comment: @ErikEidt "[bx] dereferences the address held in bx".What do you mean?

Comment: Every byte of the string has a memory address.  Every memory address of the string holds a byte.  Using a memory address to obtain (or store) a byte (or larger) is called a [dereference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator).  In that assembly language the usage of the `[]`s around the register name indicates a dereference operator in that line of assembly code, though the actual dereference it will do depends on the opcode and other context, namely source vs. target.

Comment: Memory can be indexed or dereferenced; memory can be referred to because every memory location has a unique address.  Registers don't have addresses; the registers can be named in instructions, but cannot be referred to.  Any data structure that is either variable length (strings and arrays broadly are variable length data structures) requires memory since only memory has can be indexed or dereferenced.  Register are used to hold memory addresses for purposes of accessing those data structures.

Answer (score 1):

In Intel-style assembly code, square brackets (`[`..`]`) mean dereference -- access the memory pointed at by the thing in the brackets.

So `[bx]` means access the memory pointed at by the `bx` register, and `move dl, [bx]` means load a byte from that address and put it into `dl`

Comment: Couldnt we just write mov dl,bx?

Comment: No, that would move from the register `bx` not from the memory pointed at by `bx` (and would be an error since `bx` and `dl` have different sizes)

Comment: @MissMulan: In C, if you have `char *str = array;`,  you need to write `char dl = *str;`, not `char dl = str` (different sizes, and in C the compiler cares about types.  You could do `uintptr_t dx = (uintptr_t)str;` but that has a different meaning, copying the 16-bit pointer like `mov dx, bx`, not accessing the pointed-to memory like `mov dl, [bx]` or `mov dx, [bx]`.)